# Passing a file from Activity to fragment using Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Ok So I'm trying yo pass any file from file manager(Activity) to the fragment. Here is my code:

```
               Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
                    bundle.putString ("File", chosenFile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), UploadFragment.class);
                    intent.putExtras (bundle);
                    startActivity (new Intent (FileExplore.this, UploadFragment.class));
```

The app crashes in the Logcat is states unable to find explicit activity class. Which then gives me the line where the code error occurs which is startActivity(new Intent(.....). Is the error because I'm not sending the Intent correctly from Activity to a Fragment?

In the Fragment I have the following code under the button.setOnclickListener().

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity (), FileExplore.class);
            startActivity (intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't create fragment or send data to it using Intent.

You can put a fragment inside you activity by calling: 
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaciton().add(R.id.id_of_container, new UploadFragment(), false).commit();`

If you want to pass data from activity to fragment you do it on fragment creation using `setArgument()` method, for example:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
bundle.putString ("File", chosenFile);

UploadFragment fragment = new UploadFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: I get an error saying .add() cannot not be applied to an actual argument.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad add method dont have boolean as third parameter, I've updated my answer